# Extra space due to \patchcmd

Tags: spacing, etoolbox

It seems that `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` adds three unwanted spaces, as shown below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\tracingall%                            3 spaces in log file
\def\test{1}]\patchcmd\test{1}{2}{}{}[% 3 spaces between brackets in output
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Issue a number of `\unskip`s: `\def\test{1}]\patchcmd\test{1}{2}{}{}\unskip\unskip\unskip[`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two spaces come from calls of `\scantokens`, the third from an unprotected end-of-line in the code.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% Add \ifhmode\unskip\fi
\protected\def\etb@ifscanable#1{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\etb@resrvda{%
    \def\noexpand\etb@resrvda####1\detokenize{macro}:####2->####3&{%
      ####1\def\string\etb@resrvda####2{####3}}%
    \edef\noexpand\etb@resrvda{\noexpand\etb@resrvda\meaning#1&}}%
  \etb@resrvda
  \makeatletter
  \scantokens\expandafter{\etb@resrvda}%
  %%% ADDITION
  \ifhmode\unskip\fi
  %%% END ADDITION
  \expandafter\endgroup\ifx#1\etb@resrvda
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\def\etb@patchcmd@scantoks#1{%
  \edef\etb@resrvda{\endgroup
    \unexpanded{\makeatletter\scantokens}{#1}%
    \catcode\number`\@=\the\catcode`\@\relax}%
  \etb@resrvda
  %%% ADDITION
  \ifhmode\unskip\fi
  %%% END ADDITION
}
% Fix a missing `%'
\protected\long\def\etb@ifpattern#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\etb@resrvda{%
    \def\noexpand\etb@resrvda####1\detokenize{#2}####2&{%
      \endgroup\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\ifblank{####2}}%
    \edef\noexpand\etb@resrvda{\noexpand\etb@resrvda
      \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning#1\detokenize{#2}&}%
    \noexpand\etb@resrvda}% <---------- MISSING IN etoolbox.sty
  \etb@resrvda\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\def\test{1}]\patchcmd\test{1}{2}{}{}[% brackets for checking

][% for check
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the best strategy is never using `\patchcmd` in horizontal mode.

The corresponding command `\xpatchcmd` from `regexpatch` is free from this problem.

---

A different patch could be adding `\@empty` at the end of the two `\scantokens:

```
\protected\def\etb@ifscanable#1{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\etb@resrvda{%
    \def\noexpand\etb@resrvda####1\detokenize{macro}:####2->####3&{%
      ####1\def\string\etb@resrvda####2{####3}}%
    \edef\noexpand\etb@resrvda{\noexpand\etb@resrvda\meaning#1&}}%
  \etb@resrvda
  \makeatletter
  \scantokens\expandafter{\etb@resrvda\@empty}% <---- ADDED
  \expandafter\endgroup\ifx#1\etb@resrvda
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\def\etb@patchcmd@scantoks#1{%
  \edef\etb@resrvda{\endgroup
    \unexpanded{\makeatletter\scantokens}{#1\noexpand\@empty}% <---- ADDED
    \catcode\number`\@=\the\catcode`\@\relax}%
  \etb@resrvda}
```

In the second case, `\noexpand\@empty` is needed, because we're inside an `\edef`. However this requires more testing than I'm inclined to do.

I'd have liked patching the two commands with `\patchcmd` itself, but they resist it.

Comment: shouldn't you have patched etoolbox with patchcmd for a satisfying virtuous circle?

Comment: with `\endlinechar` set to `-1` one avoids the spaces coming from `\scantokens`: `\begingroup\endlinechar-1 \patchcmd\test{1}{2}{}{}\global\let\test\test\endgroup`. There remains the space you identified in `\etb@ifpattern`.

Comment: Are you going to contact CTAN about this? The code has the awkward 'author-maintained' status, but presumably a way around that can be found to fix it.

Comment: @JosephWright I'm inclined to avoid proposing the insertion of `\ifhmode\unskip\fi`. The missing `%` should be fixed.